# Firebase Realtime Database Trigger inactive after idle period

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase project with a Firebase Function that triggers when changes are made to a node in the Realtime Database. I deployed and tested the Firebase Functions 2 months ago and everything was working fine. When I now update a node in the database the Firebase Function does not trigger anymore. Why is the Firebase Function not triggered anymore? Are the database listeners disabled after a certain period of inactivity? I dont think this is due to the instance spin up time because after several minutes of waiting the function was still not triggered. When I redeploy the exact same functions everything works again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update: 22 Mar 2019**

See comment below by Firebase team member:

> This limitation was removed as of today. You will have to redeploy
>   your Cloud Functions one final time, but after that they shouldn't be
>   auto-removed after 30 days anymore.

---

I don't find this issue addressed in the Firebase documentation but it is in the [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#time_limits):

> Max inactivity time for background functions = 30 days
>
> The maximum amount of time that a background function can be kept
>   without any invocation. Functions that are not invoked even once
>   during this time may enter a state in which new events will not
>   trigger them anymore. If this happens, such functions have to be
>   redeployed to start working again. Note: This inactive state is not
>   reflected in the UI, CLI, or API in any way.

**Edit:**

They have added it in the firebase documentation now: [documentation link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas)

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for looking this up. The only solutions I can think of is to schedule cron jobs that trigger the functions every 30 days or to automatically redeploy every 30 days. Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: @ErikvandenHoorn:  cron job or periodic redeploy seems like the only options.

Comment: I contacted Firebase Support to verify if the functions shutdown after 30 days of inactivity and to ask them how to prevent this. I will post an update once I have a response.

Comment: Got a response from Firebase support. They are aware of the issue and are exploring potential solutions but cant share any details or timelines.

Comment: I have similar issue, and I noticed that redeploying all functions at once via `firebase --only functions` doesn't seem to work. In my case, I have to redeploy individual function manually via `firebase --only functions:someFunction` for the redeployment to work. Just wanted to share until we have a better solution from the team.

Comment: *firebaser here* This limitation was removed as of today. You will have to redeploy your Cloud Functions one final time, but after that they shouldn't be auto-removed after 30 days anymore.

Comment: It's still listed here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Frank: Comment by Neal Tibrewala notes that cloud function auto-removal after 30 days of inactivity is still in the Quotas and Limits docs under Time Limits.

Comment: Good catch. That is meant to disappear after the release has been out a few weeks. I'll schedule a web site update. But rest assured: the release is out and rolled out to everyone. If you're still seeing functions (that were redeployed since 3/22) auto-removed after 30 days, [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with Firebase support.